# If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets and $ X \cap Y \neq \emptyset \land X \not\subseteq Y \land Y \not\subseteq X$ , what is the cardinality of $X \cup Y$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is an exercise inspired by Terence Tao's *Analysis I* book.

Note: If $X$ is a finite set, Tao uses $\text{#}(X)$ to denote the cardinality of $X$.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, what is the cardinality of $X \cup Y$?

I broke this problem down into three different cases...and it is **the third case** that is giving me trouble. The cases are as follows:

1. $X \cap Y = \emptyset$
2. $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset \land (X \subsetneq Y \lor Y \subsetneq X)$
3. $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset \land X \not\subseteq Y \land Y \not\subseteq X$

---

For all cases, I have chosen the following notation: $\text{#}(X)=n$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\text{#}(Y)=m$ where $m \in \mathbb N$.

Case 1 results in the conclusion that $\text{#}(X \cup Y) = n+m$

Case 2 results in the conclusion that either $\text{#}(X \cup Y) = m$ or $\text{#}(X \cup Y) = n$ depending on which set is acting as the subset.

And then we arrive at Case 3. Now, intuitively, I can see that Case 3 will result in the statement $\text{#}(X \cup Y) = \text{#}(X\setminus Y)+\text{#}(Y\setminus X)+\text{#}(X \cap Y)$. However, I am having a very difficult time constructing a bijective function (derived from **arbitrary bijective functions**) that can carry this out. I will call this function "$g$".

I emphasize the "arbitrary" bijective functions because this is what we are starting out with in our assumptions...i.e. we have the following:

$f^X: X \to \{i \in \mathbb N:1\leq i \leq n\} $ and $f^X$ is bijective.

$f^Y: Y \to \{i \in \mathbb N:1 \leq i \leq m\}$ and $f^Y$ is bijective.

I have figured out how to construct $g$ if $\text{#}(X \cap Y) = 1$, but am struggling to generalize this to an arbitrary number $k \gt 1$. The correct notation for encoding this is not something I am familiar with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**As a side note**, if  $\text{#}(X \cap Y) = 1$, where I call this one element $c^*$, the way in which I generated $g$ was basically by creating two additional functions $f^{X -\{c^*\}}$ and $f^{Y -\{c^*\}}$, which behave as "shifting functions" as detailed below:

$f^{X -\{c^*\}}: X-\{c^*\} \to \{i \in \mathbb N:1\leq i \leq n-1\}$

$f^{X -\{c^*\}}(a)= \begin{cases}
f^{X}(a) &\text{ if } f^{X}(a) \lt f^{X}(c^*)\\
f^{X}(a)-1 &\text{ if } f^{X}(a) \gt f^{X}(c^*)\\
\end{cases}$

$f^{Y -\{c^*\}}: Y-\{c^*\} \to \{i \in \mathbb N:1\leq i \leq m-1\}$

$f^{Y -\{c^*\}}(a)= \begin{cases}
f^{Y}(a) &\text{ if } f^{Y}(a) \lt f^{Y}(c^*)\\
f^{Y}(a)-1 &\text{ if } f^{Y}(a) \gt f^{Y}(c^*)\\
\end{cases}$

Because these are bijective functions, I could then construct $g$ as follows:

$g:\{i \in \mathbb N: 1 \leq i \leq n+m-1\} \to X \cup Y$

$g(i)=\begin{cases}
\big(f^{X-\{c^*\}}\big)^{-1}(i) &:1 \leq i \leq n-1\\
\Big(f^{Y-\{c^*\}}\Big)^{-1}\big(i-(n-1)\big) &:n-2 \leq i \leq (m-1)+(n-1)\\ 
c^* &: i=m+n-1\\
\end{cases}$

I do not see any easy way of generalizing this to arbitrary values greater than $1$!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really your question, but in the case 3), $$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|.$$

Comment: Yes, I can see that this is intuitively true. I phrase it slightly differently as: $\text{#}(X \cup Y) = \text{#}(X\setminus Y)+\text{#}(Y\setminus X)+\text{#}(X \cap Y)$ But what is the proof (that is basically my question).

Comment: exactly what you wrote ! As far as you know that $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then your proof (on your previous comment) is perfectly correct.

Comment: Umm. I think you may have misunderstood my post. I am trying to derive a proof for case 3. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: But the proof is that : $$|X\cup Y|=|X\setminus Y|+|Y\setminus X|+|X\cap Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|.$$ This is the proof. @S.Cramer

Comment: That does not make sense. I am trying to prove that statement by constructing bijective functions.

Comment: What doesn't make sense ?

Comment: I am trying to prove that the cardinality of $X \cup Y$ is equal to the cardinality of $X$ plus the cardinality of $Y$ minus the cardinality of $X \cap Y$.

Comment: Then the proof is exactly what I wrote earlier ! Or if you prefer : $$|X\cup Y|=|X\cup (Y\setminus X)|=|X|+|Y\setminus X|=|X|+|Y|+|X\cap Y|.$$ Now, if this is not a valuable proof for you, then sorry for you. But this is a correct proof for the math community ;-)

Comment: From what I understand about this subject, the definition of cardinality equality between finite sets is constructing a bijective function between whatever set you are interested in (in this case $X \cup Y$) and some finite subset of the natural numbers (usually of the form $\{i \in \mathbb N: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$. Your proof does not do this...hence my confusion.

Comment: Use your shifting functions to shift by more than 1 then.

Comment: @Mathy I don't think it is that simple. Or if it is, I certainly don't see how to write it down.

Comment: @Mathy to clarify why I don't think it works like that, your suggestion would require that the elements in the intersection are being mapped to consecutive natural numbers. This is not necessarily true because the bijective functions $f^X$ and $f^Y$ are arbitrary. The elements in the intersections could be mapped to completely unrelated (i.e. non-consecutive) natural numbers.

Comment: @S.Cramer: I think it's lost of energy for us, but anyway. As far as you proved that $$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|\tag{E}$$ whenever $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then just apply this formula to $X\cup Y=X\cup (Y\setminus X)$. Since $X$ and $Y\setminus X$ are disjoint, $(E)$ gives you that $$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y\setminus X|\tag{1}.$$ Now, $Y=(Y\setminus X)\cup (X\cap Y)$. Since $Y\setminus X$ and $X\cap Y$ are disjoint, by (E) $$|Y|=|Y\setminus X|+|X\cap Y|,$$ or said differently, $$|Y\setminus X|=|Y|-|X\cap Y|\tag{2}.$$ Combine (1) and (2), gives $$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cup Y|.$$ QED.

Comment: @Surb Ahhh. I see. Thank you...and sorry for the confusion. I thought that maybe you were going along the route of clever set equivalencies, but didn’t play around with it enough. This is much simpler. Should I just abandon the bijective function construction approach?

Comment: You are welcome :-) Bijective function approche is useless with finite set. But for infinite set, you can't avoid them.@S.Cramer